# How should I connect misaligned round ducts inside a cabinet?

Tags: hvac, kitchens, vent, ducts, exhaust-fan

New cabinets, new over-the-range microwave, old 7" duct from the previous range hood  — but the microwave exhaust adapter doesn't quite line up with the duct, and the distance is pretty short:

[image]

What would you do here?

- The shortest rigid adjustable elbow I've found would require cutting the vent about flush with the top of the cabinet, and getting the exact fit in-place seems like it would be tough.
- Maybe I could cut away a bit less length and use a flexible connection?
- Just start calling local HVAC places or a handyman? Am I just asking for trouble?

Comment: Do you plan to leave it installed with that extension cord?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no reason you couldn't use a short length of 7" flexible duct.  Obviously, a long flex is a bad idea because it restricts flow, but for that few-inch offset, flex will do you fine.

Answer (score 0):

Flex does not meet code so don't. It would not do to have a fire and realize your homeowners insurance wouldn't cover the losses because you didn't install per code.

Comment: You probably should be a fair bit more specific when talking about whether stuff does or doesn't meet Code -- really helps to actually *cite* the Code section you're talking about (in your case, IMC 505.3, which simply requires the duct to be made from metal and have a smooth inner wall, something that is available in flex these days albeit not typical)